# Error: Tag appears more than once (Field=9215)

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

ICE just updated their service and now my cannot connect to it, I get this error message:

8=FIX.4.49=11335=334=1149=27350=152=20161116-16:15:19.92056=ICE45=1058=Tag appears more than once371=9215372=d373=1310=223

I am using QuickFixn V1.3 and I already set:
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N 
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N

I also already added this to my data dictionary:

< field number="9215" name="MiFIDRegulatedMarket" type="STRING"/>
< field number="9216" name="AONAllowed" type="STRING"/>

And no luck, ICE released the new version just last week, before that it was working fine, so, has anyone had this issue in the past 3 days? any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You added the new fields to the set of fields, but you didn't update the message definitions to indicate that a field was added *to that message*.

Your engine doesn't know that 9215 & 9216 belong to the repeating group within the SecurityDefinition message.  As soon as it sees 9215, it decides the group has just ended and that tag 9215 belongs to the top-level of the message body.

Please take a minute to read (or reread) this doc page:
http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html